# php table values appearing incorrectly

Tags: php

I am trying to make a table, where the $f1,$f2..etc. will be at the top, and the min increments by five at the left column. 
 However, I keep ending up with the $f1 header generated all along the side instead of the min increment. 
The actual values in the table should be the header multiplied by the sidebar. My requests work fine, but the actual cells aren't the way i intend to have them.

```
<table class="table">
<?php 
$max = 60;
$min = 30;

$f1= 5;
$f2= 10;
$f3= 15;
$f4= 20;
$f5= 25;

$count = array($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5);
$NumRows = $max;
echo '<br />';
for($i=$min;$i<=$NumRows;$i=$i+5){
    echo '<tr>';
    for($j=0; $j <= 4; $j++) {
        if($i ==$min || $j ==0) {
            echo '<td class="cell1">'.$count[$j].'</td>';

        }
        else {
            echo '<td class="cell2">'.$i*$count[$j].'</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

it should essentially look like a multiplication table.

[image: i]

Comment: Can you provide a sample set of all the php variables you are fetching from request?

Comment: @ParthManaktala i've just edited with some example values!

Comment: Also please provide the expected output.

Comment: @ParthManaktala the expected output is a plain html page with a table, how should I add it into the table? Or should i explain it more?

Comment: May be you can attach a screenshot of that table, that would help

Comment: what is `|| $j ==0` for if you don't want `$f1` being repeated? Can you provide what you expect the table to be?

Comment: @ParthManaktala I've added an image of the way its meant to look. The leftmost column is meant to be the min, incrementing by 5 (30,35,40..60) while the top is the values i put in the count array.

Comment: @KamyarMirzavaziri i've tried to add an image in the question, i hope it provides a bit of clarity

Comment: @saxagi7 This is what code generates, I meant what it should generate?

Comment: @saxagi7 your screenshot doesn't make any sense , 5*10 = 350 ? or i am reading it wrong ?

Comment: From what I can see, the code you provided prints the exact same table from the picture except it has more rows, I can't understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified example without all these `for` loops and `if`s ([fiddle](https://3v4l.org/BDu0D)):

```
echo '<table>';
$max = 60;
$min = 30;

$f1= 5;
$f2= 10;
$f3= 15;
$f4= 20;
$f5= 25;

$count = array($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5);
$NumRows = $max;

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
foreach ($count as $item) {
    echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';

for($i=$min;$i<=$NumRows;$i=$i+5){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
    foreach ($count as $item) {
        echo '<td>' . $i * $item . '</td>';
    }    
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is  solution. You need to fill first column with `$i` instead of `$count[$j]`

```
<table class="table">
<?php 
    $max = 60;
    $min = 30;
    $increment = 5;

    $f1= 5;
    $f2= 10;
    $f3= 15;
    $f4= 20;
    $f5= 25;

    $count = array($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5);
    echo '<tr><td></td>';
    foreach ( range(1, count($count)) as $cell ) {
        echo '<td>' . $cell * $increment . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    for ( $i=$min; $i <= $max; $i += $increment ) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="cell1">' . $i . '</td>';
        for ( $j=0; $j <= 4; $j++ ) {
                echo '<td class="cell2">' . $i * $count[$j] . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: this works perfectly, but I am missing the values for the top column (should have 5 above 150, 10 above 300) etc. How can i do this? thanks!

Comment: Does't it give one extra row with elements 150 300 450 600 750 ?

Comment: @saxagi7 I've changed answer

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going

```
<?php 
$max = 60;
$min = 30;

$f1= 5;
$f2= 10;
$f3= 15;
$f4= 20;
$f5= 25;

$count = array($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5);
$NumRows = $max;
echo '<br />';
for($i=$min;$i<=$NumRows;$i=$i+5){
    echo '<tr>';
    for($j=0; $j <= 4; $j++) {
        if($i == $min){
            echo '<td class="cell1" style="color:red">'. $count[$j] .'</td>';;
        }
        else if($j ==0) {
            echo '<td class="cell1" style="color:blue">'. $count[$j] . "(" . $i . ")" .  '</td>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<td class="cell2">'.$i*$count[$j].'</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove the style later, it is just for reference and understanding, Also if the second `if-else`. You can have both the values so select if you need the increment i.e 5 or `$count[$j]` which will give you 30,35 etc